# Error in merging of 2 different ranges VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

i have faced with issue while merging some dynamic ranges through VBA.
Once it is standard range like Range("A3:E4"), all is fine and i have 2 lines in values of the range.

screen from add watch

[image]

But once i want to merge different ranges like Range("A3:E3,A4:E4") i am receiving only value of the first range. Who knows how it can be fixed, and how can i correctly merge different ranges in VBA, to use their values later?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Each `Range` has a property named `Areas` which contain the sub-tables of cells.

Consider the code below

```
Dim r As Range    
Set r = Union(Range("F2:F6"), Range("H2:H6"))    
Dim a As Range
For Each a In r.Areas
    Debug.Print a.Address
Next
```

which prints out

```
$F$2:$F$6
$H$2:$H$6
```

So each area would be used to define it own array of values

```
Dim a_vals as Variant, b_vals as Variant
a_vals = r.Areas(1).Value2
b_vals = r.Areas(2).Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert working with arrays, but these two methods have helped me working with ranges and merging them into 1D arrays separated by a character

**Method 1: Define separate ranges and merge their content into 1D array**

```
Public Sub MergeTwoRangesIntoArray()
    
    ' Get range 1 values into 1d array
    Dim range1Values As Variant
    range1Values = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.Index(Range("A1:A10"), 0, 1))

    ' Get range 2 values into 1d array
    Dim range2Values As Variant
    range2Values = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.Index(Range("B1:B10"), 0, 1))
    
    ' Define and redimension an array to hold the concatenated area and category values
    Dim mergedRangeValues() As Variant
    ReDim mergedRangeValues(1 To UBound(range1Values))
    
    ' Concatenate the area and category values and store them in an array
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To UBound(range1Values)
        mergedRangeValues(counter) = range1Values(counter) & "|" & range2Values(counter)
    Next counter
    
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

**Method 2: Define multi area range and merge each areas' content into 1D array**

```
Public Sub MergeTwoAreasIntoArray()

    Dim multiRange As Range
    Set multiRange = Range("A1:A10,B1:B10,C1:C11")
    
    Dim totalAreas As Long
    totalAreas = multiRange.Areas.Count
    
    Dim rangeValues() As Variant
    ReDim rangeValues(1 To totalAreas)
    
    Dim areaCounter As Long
    For areaCounter = 1 To totalAreas
    
        ' Get range 1 values into 1d array
        rangeValues(areaCounter) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.Index(multiRange.Areas(areaCounter), 0, 1))
    
    Next areaCounter
    
    ' Get the upper bound of the range values (first range)
    Dim totalRangeValues As Long
    totalRangeValues = UBound(rangeValues(1))
    
    Dim resultArray As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(1 To totalRangeValues)

    Dim itemCounter As Long
    For itemCounter = 1 To totalRangeValues
    
        Dim rangeCounter As Long
        For rangeCounter = 1 To totalAreas
        
            resultArray(itemCounter) = resultArray(itemCounter) & "|" & rangeValues(rangeCounter)(itemCounter)
        Next rangeCounter
    
    Next itemCounter
    
End Sub
```